# Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports

Tags: node.js-fs

[ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

```
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1374:21:
  1374 │         let result = await callback({
       ╵                      ^

at packageEntryFailure (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48252:17)
at resolvePackageEntry (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48249:5)
at tryNodeResolve (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48019:20)
at Context.resolveId (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:47769:28)
at Object.resolveId (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51029:64)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:68116:21
at async file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48592:34
at async requestCallbacks.on-resolve (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1374:22)
at async handleRequest (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:732:11)
```

This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

```
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1293:20:
  1293 │       let promise = setup({
       ╵                     ^

at setup (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48572:19)
at handlePlugins (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1293:21)
at buildOrContextImpl (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:979:5)
at Object.buildOrContext (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:788:5)
at D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:68
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.context (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:27)
at Object.context (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2048:58)
at prepareEsbuildOptimizerRun (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:52756:35)
```

The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" was triggered by this import

```
node_modules/request/lib/har.js:3:17:
  3 │ var fs = require('fs')
    ╵                  ~~~~
```

^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
PS D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay> npm run dev

> razorpay@0.0.0 dev
> vite

VITE v5.2.6  ready in 666 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h + enter to show help
Error:   Failed to scan for dependencies from entries:
D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/index.html

X [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-scan]

```
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1374:21:
  1374 │         let result = await callback({
       ╵                      ^

at packageEntryFailure (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48252:17)
at resolvePackageEntry (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48249:5)
at tryNodeResolve (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48019:20)
at Context.resolveId (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:47769:28)
at Object.resolveId (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51029:64)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async resolve (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51354:26)
at async file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51539:34
at async requestCallbacks.on-resolve (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1374:22)
at async handleRequest (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:732:11)
```

This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

```
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1293:20:
  1293 │       let promise = setup({
       ╵                     ^

at setup (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51529:19)
at handlePlugins (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1293:21)
at buildOrContextImpl (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:979:5)
at Object.buildOrContext (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:788:5)
at D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:68
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.context (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:27)
at Object.context (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2048:58)
at prepareEsbuildScanner (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51301:26)
```

The plugin "vite:dep-scan" was triggered by this import

```
src/App.jsx:3:17:
  3 │ var fs = require('fs')
    ╵                  ~~~~


at failureErrorWithLog (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1651:15)
at D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1059:25
at runOnEndCallbacks (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1486:45)
at buildResponseToResult (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1057:7)
at D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1069:9
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at requestCallbacks.on-end (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1068:54)
at handleRequest (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:732:17)
at handleIncomingPacket (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:757:7)
at Socket.readFromStdout (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:680:7)
```

^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
PS D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay> npm run dev

> > 

> razorpay@0.0.0 dev
> vite

VITE v5.2.6  ready in 697 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h + enter to show help
nX [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

```
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1374:21:
  1374 │         let result = await callback({
       ╵                      ^

at packageEntryFailure (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48252:17)
at resolvePackageEntry (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48249:5)
at tryNodeResolve (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48019:20)
at Context.resolveId (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:47769:28)
at Object.resolveId (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:51029:64)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:68116:21
at async file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48592:34
at async requestCallbacks.on-resolve (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1374:22)
at async handleRequest (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:732:11)
```

This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:

```
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1293:20:
  1293 │       let promise = setup({
       ╵                     ^

at setup (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:48572:19)
at handlePlugins (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1293:21)
at buildOrContextImpl (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:979:5)
at Object.buildOrContext (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:788:5)
at D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:68
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.context (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:27)
at Object.context (D:\MERNstack\RamanaSoft-internship\razorpay\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2048:58)
at prepareEsbuildOptimizerRun (file:///D:/MERNstack/RamanaSoft-internship/razorpay/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-BBHrJRja.js:52756:35)
```

The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" was triggered by this import

```
node_modules/request/lib/har.js:3:17:
  3 │ var fs = require('fs')
    ╵                  ~~~~
```

when i run command npm run dev. i'm facing this isssue

need to fix this issue